# Not able to view my code in MPLAB X IDE..!

Tags: microchip, mplabx

I am trying to open my project (.C file) in MPLAB X ide (v5.15), but i cannot see my code, instead it opens up a rather weird window. It shows some history tab (of which i have no idea). I have attached a Screenshot. Could someone help me figure this out? How do i view my actual code in the editor?

PS: I took a backup of entire Hard disk of my old pc to new one and now I am trying to open those old .X projects in IDE installed on new PC.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to create new project? Does that new project work?

Comment: Try "Window:Reset Windows".

Comment: I tried both creating new project and resetting windows, none seems to work.@Chupacabras @Phil G